# What does posterior "over" parameters $\alpha$ exactly mean?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, terminology, posterior, notation

From my understanding the posterior "over" parameters $\alpha$ is

$$p(D|\alpha)$$

and not

$$p(\alpha|D),$$

is it correct?

Comment: Given different people might use the same phrase to mean somewhat different things, some context and definitions might help. Presumably $\alpha$ is a parameter vector, but does it include all the parameters? What's $D$? Who is using the term *posterior over parameters*, and what else are they saying near it?

Comment: In the example of the question, with $D$ I generically meant "data", and $\alpha$ a vector of parameters... (what do you mean with "all" the parameters, and why it matters?). Here just two examples that seem to contradict my understanding. Look for "posterior over":http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~parg/projects/ica/riz/Thesis/thesis019.html https://astro.uni-bonn.de/~kbasu/ObsCosmo/Slides2013/obs_cos_4_2013.pdf

Comment: If there are several parameters, for example $\mu, \sigma$, and $\kappa$ (say), and $\alpha=(\sigma,\kappa)$, then there's an additional possible meaning of the phrase -- $p(\mu|D,\alpha)$.

Comment: If the options in your question are the only two possible, I could only assume the second is the intent. The first is a likelihood, not a posterior.

Comment: Note that in both your example links, there are in fact additional parameters the first time the phrase is used (hyperparameters included in $M$ in the first, and everything but $\theta_2$ in the second). [Generally speaking, something like $p(\alpha|D,M)$ will be nearer the intent, but sometimes "over" might be used to mean conditioning on $\alpha$, as in $p(\theta|\alpha,D,M)$; but if that happens, it's almost always obvious from context]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.

The standard convention is that *posterior* [distribution] over parameter $\alpha$ is

$$
P(\alpha | D)
$$

Just like $P(x)$ is some distribution **over** $x$, $P(\alpha | D)$ is a distribution **over** $\alpha$.

Posterior here means that we condition $\alpha$ on given data $D$. If we didn't, it'd be a *prior* (in Bayesian terms) [distribution] $P(\alpha)$.

$P(D|\alpha)$ is not a distribution over $\alpha$, it's called *likelihood*.